# A folder and a file with the same name in the same location

Tags: nautilus, files, directory, 18.04

I'm on 14.04 about to move up to 18.04. In that version of Ubuntu can I have a folder and a file in the same location with the same name?

My use case is that I have html files without the .html extension, that I push up to AWS S3, where I serve a few websites. Leaving off the .html extension enables me to have clean urls for the websites. And S3 is perfectly happy to have directories and files with the same name, and thankfully they serve the html file rather than a folder if you navigate to the URL that is a file and a folder.

This would be a nice to have in Ubuntu. I could have an html file called 'articles' and a folder called articles, and then my URLs would be "RESTful."

`example.com/articles/title` would give you the article with that title, and `example.com/articles` would serve up a list of articles.

Anyhow, AWS already does this, I was just hoping Nautilus, or Ubuntu could handle this so I don't have to go through an awkward coding nightmare where my local directories have different names from my server directories.

Does this work in 18.04 or can anyone think of a good work-around?

Comment: There's some sort of mistake in the question. What you're asking is dependent on the filesystem, not the type of GNU/Linux distro -- but the standard GNU/Linux filesystems (ext3, ext4, etc.) all don't allow an identically named file and folder in the same directory. Also, naming your HTML file `index.html` and putting them in a folder called e.g. `example.com/title`, so the full path is `example.com/title/index.html`, is one common way to accomplish what you're asking, because browsers won't show the `index.html` if you just go to `https://example.com/title` then.

Comment: @Harry These are good points. Would you mind if I use them in my answer?

Comment: Thanks so much! This is helpful. Doing the folder hack requires changing every file, instead I might do a hack that just renames my folders that end in something special on their way up to S3.

Comment: @Harry This is *not* dependent on the filesystem. (You're right that it doesn't depend on the distro, either, though.) See [Same folder and file name in same location](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662911/same-folder-and-file-name-in-same-location) and [Why can't I have a folder and a file with the same name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/why-cant-i-have-a-folder-and-a-file-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Linux doesn't have folders. Linux has directories. Directories *are* files. Ergo, the question whether you can have a directory and a file with the same name is trivial, since a directory is a file, and the question thus simply becomes "can I have two files with the same name", the answer to which should be obvious. Where does this myth that Linux has folders come from? It is the cause of *so many* questions and problems, all of which could simply be avoided, if that myth didn't exist.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think distinguishing between "directory" and "folder" is irrelevant to this. Are there OSes that let you have a file and folder with the same name--*actually* with the same name, not just displaying as though they do in some graphical browser that trims suffixes or hides some characters--in the same place? [Some people claim "directory" and "folder" don't mean the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078676), but the distinction is not that some OSes have one and others the other. It is no more wrong to call directories folders on Ubuntu than Windows. It is not wrong at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The OS and file system do not allow this

Ubuntu and its file systems (ext3, ext4, etc.) doesn't allow an identically named file and folder in the same directory.

Therefore, `nautilus` does not allow renaming a folder to an existing file name.

However, Ubuntu (GNU/Linux in general) file systems are case sensitive. You can have a folder called **Articles** and a file called **articles** in the same location. Note the folder name starts with a capital `A`, while the file name starts with a small `a`.

You can use any CaPiTaLiZaTion conventions you want for your folders and files.

## An alternative

An alternative is to create a file called `index.html` inside each folder where you want the folder and the file to have the same name. Naming your HTML file `index.html` and putting them in a folder called e.g. `example.com/articles/title`, so the full path is `example.com/articles/title/index.html`, will also accomplish what you're asking.

When one types `https://example.com/articles/title` the web server will serve the `index.html` page and browsers won't show the `index.html`. It will show only `https://example.com/articles/title`.

Similarly, you can have a file called `https://example.com/article/index.html`to show what you want when one types `https://example.com/article`.

Thanks to [Harry](https://askubuntu.com/users/704221/harry) for the alternative and some other points.

Comment: Beat me to it, lol.

Comment: If I'm going to write a work around, I'll probably just work around for the directories. There's far less of them, than files. It'll make navigating much easier. S3 supports my need, so I'll just need to work around for my local setup. Bah... work arounds suck : (

Comment: Much of this answer is okay, but the suggestion that it's *just* the filesystem, and not the OS, that prevents a directory and regular file with the same basename from residing in the same directory, makes little sense. Is there some filesystem, on any Unix-like OS, that *really* facilitates this? Suppose `/foo` contained a regular file `bar` and also a separate directory `bar`. How would they be distinguished? Which would [the `stat` system call](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/stat.2.html) return information about when the path `/foo/bar` were passed as its first argument?

Comment: @EliahKagan this is a fair point. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for editing! But I think this post still suggests that a combination of Ubuntu and some filesystem could allow this. I don't want to edit myself, as we may disagree, but I don't think it really *depends* on much. I don't think any OS or filesystem allows this (though some approach it [with versioning semantics](https://superuser.com/a/517116)). The only reason I'm not saying this more definitively is there's a lot of weird stuff out there (but see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/662914)). I'd suggest saying "Neither the OS nor its filesystem allow it" instead of "It depends on..."

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks again. Please edit the answer. I don't know enough to disagree.

Comment: @user68186 I've edited. I went with the more neutral phrase "The OS and file system do not allow this." I believe this is sufficient to avoid giving the impression that the filesystem *could* facilitate it. As usual, please definitely feel free to edit this yourself to change it again, if you like (or to revert it altogether).

Answer (score 2):

Question is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550299/aws-s3-hosting-url-rewrite. If you look in the comments, you'll even see that his precise use case is removing the .html from his URLs.

While the accepted answer provides a valid, working solution, I think this is a case of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In this case, what you **really need** is a [URL Rewriting system](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners), which dispenses with the naming convention problem altogether. While the previous article does not apply to AWS S3, it explains the concept fairly well. Unfortunately, since S3 is not a web server per se, it doesn't have URL Rewrite functionality, but it does have [Webpage Redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) which, as stated in the duplicate question's answer, might be able to do this.